# How to configure Webpack with babel to recognize static properties of class?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Each of my models has its own static property, but with current configurations they are undefined.
Here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react","@babel/typescript","@babel/env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/transform-runtime","@babel/plugin-transform-classes"]
}
```

Webpack conf

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: {
      compact: true,
    },
  },
```

P.S this is ejected configuration from create-react-app